# App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP resource

Tags: ios, socket.io

[image]

I am using Socket.IO library in swift and I keep getting this error:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

when I am trying to send an http request. I added the keys to plist according to the official apple documentation, but it did not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: @william-kinaan Please do not add irrelevant tags to questions. This question is not related to Swift but to iOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to correct it like this:

[image]

To make it easier, this is the correct xml in the info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

change the `localhost` to your actual server

[Check the table for NSAppTransportSecurity options](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

If you want to all communications with any domain, you can do this:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

However, you should use the latest just in the developing phase.

Comment: I did the exact same thing and I am getting this now:
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Please help..

Comment: I'm completely new to XCode. I have 7.3 so I see the same variable names **except** that they don't have *NS* in the names. So this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Another way to solve this, which I found more convenient, is to disable App Transport Security by default using the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key. So any domains you do not include in the `NSExceptionDomains` dictionary (or if you don't include `NSExceptionDomains` at all) will not be subject to App Transport Security.

[image]

Comment: Everyone gave the same answer except this one, the only one that worked! Thanks :)

Comment: I have XCode 7.1.1 and am unable to find this option

Answer (score 4):

I see a wrong key and a typo in your screenshot. Here is a working example:

[image: screen]

Comment: Thanks for this fix! I couldn't download Facebook profile info from the graph.facebook.com domain until I added that NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads exception. Works as expected now. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode project -> go to info.plist and Click + Button then Add (App Transport Security Settings)Expand, Allow Arbitrary Loads  Set YES. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in xCode 8.2. It's a little different, but editing the PLIST file you need to add this two Items in the `App Transport Security Settings` Line... :

`Allow Arbitrary Loads` and `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content`... and give them both the key `YES`.

It worked for me, hope this work for you and sorry for my English.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@William Kinaan has the best answer, but it would seem to make best sense to be sure to add the **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** underneath the exception domain "localhost" ... and not at the higher NSTransportSecurity level which opens that up to all domains.